# How can I get the txids of memblock that will be confirmed in the next blcok using bitcoin-cli?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, mempool

I want to get the txids of the (mem-pool 0 I mean the mempool block that will next to be confirmed) using bitcoin-cli.

Basicly I want to get the txids in https://mempool.space/tr/mempool-block/0 this memblock. I am looking for this for days If you help that will be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that be https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblocktemplate.html ? Though the mempools of nodes are not synchronised.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

The mempool in Bitcoin represents a collection of unconfirmed transactions, and it doesn't have a concept of "blocks" like the blockchain does. Each transaction in the mempool exists independently and is not grouped into blocks.

To retrieve the transaction IDs (`txids`) from a specific block in the Bitcoin blockchain, you can use the `getblock` command in `bitcoin-cli`. However, the mempool itself doesn't have blocks, so you won't be able to retrieve the transaction IDs in the same way as you would for confirmed blocks.

If you're specifically interested in the transactions displayed in the **Mempool Block** section on mempool.space, those are not actual blocks but rather a visual representation of the mempool transactions arranged in a block-like structure.

To retrieve the transaction IDs in that specific arrangement, you would need to use the API provided by mempool.space itself or explore their public API documentation for more details on how to fetch the mempool block data programmatically.

Here's the [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/) API documentation that you can refer to: https://mempool.space/docs/api